Augmentation on Train, Val, Test sets for low amount of images per class
What if I had 10 images per class (given 50 classes) (the case is no way to get more images), I had a plan to split them into 70/10/20 (train/val/set) or  60/20/20 (I don't know which is the best one) (I split the data evenly, which means every class would appear in every set with the same rate, i.e class 1 : 7/1/2, class 2 : 7/1/2,e.t.c). After splitting them, I'd apply data augmentation on each set seperately (I don't know how much for each image but I think I will go for 7 - 10 augmentation for each one ). Is it a good idea? What should I do to improve performance? Your ideas to make this better?
What I'm trying to do is Face Recognition with YoloV11. I want to find out if this works or even not I still want to implement it!
If data on the test set is unseen in the training process, so augmentating on the test set is alright, right? If the test set is mandatory to not be touched, what should I do?
Spliting 10 into 7/1/2 so the 1 image in the val set is likely to be "alone". That image will be flipped, filtered, etc., is it alright?
Is it possible to achieve good performance?
What if for each class, I augmentated to 50 images, used only the augmentated (which was 40) for training process, leaved the original (which was 10) for val and test sets?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Training a neural network using only 10 images per class:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ciEcM6kvr3w  And in regards to your use of YOLOv11, see the FAQ:  https://www.ccoderun.ca/programming/yolo_faq/#others and https://www.ccoderun.ca/programming/yolo_faq/#configuration_template
